# Why does this T-SQL function always return true?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net, sql-function

I wrote this function and now its always returning true...
can anybody help me?

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.ValidateBranch
(
    @BranchID   nvarchar(50),
    @Password   nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
    BEGIN
    declare @Res bit

    if exists(Select * From TPasswords Where (BranchID = @BranchID) and (isSecurity = 0) and (Pass = @Password)) 
        set @Res = 1
    else
        set @Res = 0



    RETURN @Res
    END
```

and i'm callign like so:

```
bool isValidBranch = taQueries.ValidateBranch(IDBranch, PasswordTextBox.Text) ?? false;
```

Comment: No idea, have you tried on an empty table?

Comment: You need to change the title of this question to something meaningful. Maybe something like 'Why does this T-SQL function always return true?'.

Comment: What is "taQueries" ?? Can you tell us, and if it's a class of your own, show us that code! I need to see where you actually call the T-SQL function ....

Comment: `taQueries` is a `QueriesTableAdapter` in my dataset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The T-SQL code seems fine - how do you "always get back true" - in SQL Mgmt Studio, or from your app calling this function??

How are you calling this function, can you show us that piece of code??

I quickly recreated the setup and in my case, on SQL Server 2008 R2, it works just fine when I call this function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.ValidateCenter('Center1', 'Pwd1')  -- return 1 
SELECT dbo.ValidateCenter('Center1', 'Pwd1333')  -- return 0
```

Comment: i'm using this in a C# project and added it as a Query in an ADO.Net Dataset... also tested this from SQL Express by executing and passing some existing values and some incorrect values

Comment: @Dr TJ: can you add the C# code that you're using to call this to your question?? I think the T-SQL part should work just fine...